# Show that $P(\mathbb{N})$ is equivalent to $2^\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

How would I show that $P(\mathbb{N})$ is equivalent to $2^\mathbb{N}$? The questions asks to form a theorem from the statement I just gave. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Show that the map sending $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ to its indicator function $I(A)$ is a bijection.